# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '"', expecting '-' or identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING) on line 17 in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

at line 17 I've this line of code

```
$sq="insert into batch_content(bid,sid,joining_date) values('1','$_SESSION["id"]','$date');";
```

I can't figure what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have a look at the syntax highlighting here and your error should become fairly obvious.

Comment: wrong quotes sequence

Comment: Please correct my query I'm stuck here for a long time

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP Parse/Syntax Errors; and How to solve them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18050071/php-parse-syntax-errors-and-how-to-solve-them)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrong double quote sequence

```
$sq="insert into batch_content(bid,sid,joining_date) 
        values('1','" . $_SESSION["id"] ."','$date');";
```

but remeber that you are risk of sqlinject using php  var in sql 
You should use binding_param  .. so take a look at the sql driver you are using for this

Comment: Worked Finally. But can you please answer ' ". varible." ' what is it mean?

Comment: ' ". " '  this mean that the string  are concatenaed .. in PHP the dot   `.` is for concatenating string  .. so in your case you have double quote at start and double quotes around the index in SESSION and have error .. using string concatenation is common way for these situation  ...but don't use var in sql  .. look for binding param